# Build executable CLI script with rollup

Tags: javascript, typescript, rollupjs

I'm working on a package that includes both a library and a small CLI tool. The CLI tool at `bin/cli.ts` looks something like this:

```
import yargs from 'yargs';

import myPackage from '../dist/esm/index.js';

import { someCommand } from './someCommand';

yargs.<a bunch of stuff>;
```

I would like to build this into a script where `yargs` and `myPackage` are left as imports, but `someCommand` is bundled.

My `rollup.config.js` looks like this:

```
import ts from 'rollup-plugin-ts';
import shebang from 'rollup-plugin-add-shebang';

export default [
  {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: [
      {
        file: 'dist/esm/index.js',
        format: 'esm',
      },
      {
        file: 'dist/cjs/index.js',
        format: 'cjs',
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      ts({}),
    ],
  },
  {
    input: 'bin/cli.ts',
    output: [
      {
        file: 'dist-bin/cli.js',
        format: 'esm',
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      ts({}),
      shebang({
        shebang: '#!/usr/bin/env node',
      }),
    ],
  },
];
```

The build succeeds, and `dist-bin/cli.js` exists. However, it is identical to `dist/esm/index.js` except for the added shebang — it is compiled into a module that exports all of the library's exports. It doesn't include anything relating to `yargs` or `someCommand`.

Obviously I'm doing something very wrong here. Is rollup not the right tool for the job? I know it's really designed for modules, but I'd rather not add a second system to build the script if I can avoid it.

Comment: Can you elaborate some more on what exactly you seek? The default behavior of the Rollup is to bundle everything into a single file while leaving 3rd-party packages as they are.

Comment: I just discovered the problem — I was running `rollup --config myConfig myLib/index.ts`. I should have omitted `myLib/index.ts`; it was unnecessary before I added the script build config and caused it to do the wrong thing afterward. Since the key detail isn't even in the question at all, I voted to close rather than rewriting the entire question to make it useful.